# Операции со временем в SQLite

Tags: sqlite, datetime

Хочу понять как работать с датой временем в SQLite. Изначально были даны данные на конец недели (например продали столько то товара на 06.06.2006, данная дата это конец недели). Потребовалось разбить данные по дням, чтобы потом сгруппировать по месяцам (некоторые недели попадают в 2 месяца, и поэтому часть данных надо отнести к одному месяцу, часть данных к другому).
Размножил каждую запись на 7 экземпляров (посредством кросс джойна с числами от 0 до 6, которые символизируют день от начала недели). Получилось что-то вроде такого:

[image: Результат cross join]

Теперь я хотел бы получить даты отдельных дней путем вычитания из даты конца недели количества дней, хранящихся во второй колонке. Но в SQLite нашел только DATE('столбец с датой', '-NNN days'), где вместо NNN можно вставить только определенное число, значение другого поля вставить у меня пока не выходит.
Буду благодарен за подсказки в решении данного вопроса

Comment: Добро пожаловать на _StackOverflow._  Пожалуйста, не используйте скриншоты с текстом, а пишите текст прямо в вопрос.  А лучше, когда у вас вопрос по _SQL,_ подготовить код через сервис типа https://www.db-fiddle.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам просто нужно прибавить количество дней, то вы можете
использовать конкатенацию строк:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t1 AS SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('2020-01-01'), ('2020-01-08')) AS t;
CREATE TABLE t2 AS SELECT * FROM (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6)) AS t;
SELECT DATE(t1.column1, '+' || t2.column1 || ' days') FROM t1 CROSS JOIN t2;
```

```
2020-01-01
2020-01-02
2020-01-03
2020-01-04
2020-01-05
2020-01-06
2020-01-07
2020-01-08
2020-01-09
2020-01-10
2020-01-11
2020-01-12
2020-01-13
2020-01-14
```

Comment: Спасибо, именно данная конструкция ('+' || t2.column1 || ' days') мне и была необходима